# Appium - Not able to launch the inspector

Tags: ios7.1, appium

Team,

I am facing issues launching the Inspector. I might be missing something in my configurations or setup, but not able to figure out. I am trying to connect to real device (iOS 7.1.2). Please find the below screenshots for your reference.

```
/Users/rsangili/.bash_profile: line 3: export: `2': not a valid identifier

/Users/rsangili/.bash_profile: line 6: export: `=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin:/usr/local/apache-ant/bin:/user/local/bin/node:/usr/local/bin/npm:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/rsangili/Downloads/apache-maven-3.2.1/bin': not a valid identifier

info: Welcome to Appium v1.2.2 (REV cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4)

info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
info: [debug] Non-default server args: {"app":"com.sg.application.TestApp2","udid":"0058679bc8d12f8a56243d8de88b0d7e14dc09c0","backendRetries":6,"deviceName":"iPhone","showSimulatorLog":true,"defaultCommandTimeout":7200}
warn: Deprecated server args: {"--show-sim-log":"use instead: --show-ios-log"}
info: LogLevel: debug

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 7.906 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 2.292 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: --> GET /wd/hub/sessions {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":[]}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/sessions 200 2.300 ms - 23 {"status":0,"value":[]}
info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"platformName":"iOS","platformVersion":"7.1","newCommandTimeout":"999999","automationName":"Appium","deviceName":"iPhone"}}
info: [debug] App is an iOS bundle, will attempt to run as pre-existing
info: [debug] Creating new appium session ae2a83cb-c5c5-4c20-accd-2318da804eca
info: [debug] Removing any remaining instruments sockets
info: [debug] Cleaned up instruments socket /tmp/instruments_sock
info: [debug] Setting Xcode folder
info: [debug] Setting Xcode version

info: [debug] Setting iOS SDK Version

info: [debug] iOS SDK Version set to 7.1

info: [debug] Detecting automation tracetemplate

info: [debug] Not auto-detecting udid, running on sim

info: [debug] Localizable.strings is not currently supported when using real devices.
info: [debug] Not setting locale because we're using a real device
info: [debug] Creating instruments
info: [debug] Preparing uiauto bootstrap
info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap dir:
info: [debug] Dynamic env:
info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap code:
info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap path:

error: iOS log capture failed: spawn ENOENT

info: [debug] Reusing dynamic bootstrap:
info: [debug] Fixing device was changed from:"
info: [debug] Not setting iOS and app preferences since we're on a real device
info: [debug] Starting iOS device log capture via deviceconsole
info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session

error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: spawn ENOENT

info: [debug] Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:1001:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:792:34)
info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: spawn ENOENT)","code":"ENOENT","errno":"ENOENT","syscall":"spawn","origValue":"spawn ENOENT"},"sessionId":null}
info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 526.823 ms - 197 

info: [debug] Not setting device type since we're connected to a device

info: [debug] Creating iDevice object with udid 0058679bc8d12f8a56243d8de88b0d7e14dc09c0
info: [debug] Couldn't find ideviceinstaller, trying built-in at /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/build/libimobiledevice-macosx/ideviceinstaller
info: [debug] Checking app install status using: /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/build/fruitstrap/fruitstrap isInstalled --id 0058679bc8d12f8a56243d8de88b0d7e14dc09c0 --bundle com.sg.application.TestApp2

info: [debug] App is installed.

info: [debug] fullReset not requested. No need to install.
info: [debug] Starting command proxy.
info: [debug] Instruments socket server started at /tmp/instruments_sock
info: [debug] Starting instruments

info: [debug] Instruments is at: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments
info: Launching instruments

info: [debug] Attempting to run app on real device with UDID 0058679bc8d12f8a56243d8de88b0d7e14dc09c0
info: [debug] Spawning instruments with command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate -D /tmp/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace -w 0058679bc8d12f8a56243d8de88b0d7e14dc09c0 com.sg.application.TestApp2 -e UIASCRIPT /Users/rsangili/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-3fd3829137e4c5d0.js -e UIARESULTSPATH /tmp/appium-instruments
info: [debug] And extra without-delay env: {}
info: [debug] And launch timeouts (in ms): {"global":90000}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.154 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: Instruments is ready to receive commands

info: [debug] Instruments launched. Starting poll loop for new commands.
info: [debug] Setting bootstrap config keys/values
info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: "target = $.target();\nau = $;\n$.isVerbose = true;\nautoAcceptAlerts = false;\n"

info: [debug] Sending command to instruments: target = $.target();
au = $;
$.isVerbose = true;
autoAcceptAlerts = false;

info: [debug] Socket data received (2 bytes)
info: [debug] Socket data being routed.
info: [debug] Sending command to instruments: target = $.target();
au = $;
$.isVerbose = true;
autoAcceptAlerts = false;


info: [debug] [INST] 2014-09-23 19:16:31 +0000 Debug: evaluation finished


info: [debug] [INST] 2014-09-23 19:16:31 +0000 Debug: responding with:

info: [debug] [INST] 2014-09-23 19:16:31 +0000 Debug: Running system command #1: /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js /tmp/instruments_sock 2,{"status":0,"value":false}...


info: [debug] Socket data received (28 bytes)

info: [debug] Socket data being routed.
info: [debug] Got result from instruments: {"status":0,"value":false}
info: [debug] Setting initial orientation to PORTRAIT
info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: "au.setScreenOrientation('PORTRAIT')"

info: [debug] Sending command to instruments: au.setScreenOrientation('PORTRAIT')
info: [debug] Sending command to instruments: au.setScreenOrientation('PORTRAIT')

info: [debug] [INST] 2014-09-23 19:16:32 +0000 Debug: Got new command 1 from instruments: au.setScreenOrientation('PORTRAIT')


info: [debug] [INST] 2014-09-23 19:16:32 +0000 Debug: evaluating au.setScreenOrientation('PORTRAIT')

info: [debug] [INST] 2014-09-23 19:16:32 +0000 Debug: target.setDeviceOrientation("1")


info: [debug] [INST] 2014-09-23 19:16:33 +0000 Debug: evaluation finished


info: [debug] [INST] 2014-09-23 19:16:33 +0000 Debug: responding with:

info: [debug] [INST] 2014-09-23 19:16:33 +0000 Debug: Running system command #2: /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js /tmp/instruments_sock 2,{"status":0,"value":"PORTRAIT"}...


info: [debug] Socket data received (33 bytes)

info: [debug] Socket data being routed.

info: [debug] Got result from instruments: {"status":0,"value":"PORTRAIT"}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.335 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 2.310 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.196 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.571 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 0.856 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.625 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.096 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 2.042 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.127 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 6.350 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 0.876 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.519 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 2.685 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.188 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 2.727 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.245 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.156 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.054 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.166 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.463 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.574 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 2.214 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.467 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.526 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.130 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.005 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.552 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 2.255 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: --> GET /wd/hub/sessions {}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":[]}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/sessions 200 0.918 ms - 23 {"status":0,"value":[]}
info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"platformName":"iOS","platformVersion":"7.1","newCommandTimeout":"999999","automationName":"Appium","deviceName":"iPhone"}}
info: [debug] App is an iOS bundle, will attempt to run as pre-existing
info: [debug] Creating new appium session b8e9fbae-f5e7-4225-8abf-e7c663b39be1
info: [debug] Removing any remaining instruments sockets

info: [debug] Cleaned up instruments socket /tmp/instruments_sock
info: [debug] Setting Xcode folder

info: [debug] Setting Xcode version

info: [debug] Setting iOS SDK Version

info: [debug] iOS SDK Version set to 7.1

info: [debug] Detecting automation tracetemplate

info: [debug] Not auto-detecting udid, running on sim

info: [debug] Localizable.strings is not currently supported when using real devices.
info: [debug] Not setting locale because we're using a real device
info: [debug] Creating instruments
info: [debug] Preparing uiauto bootstrap

info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap dir:
info: [debug] Dynamic env:

info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap code:
info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap path:

info: [debug] Reusing dynamic bootstrap:

info: [debug] Fixing device was changed from:"

error: iOS log capture failed: spawn ENOENT

info: [debug] Not setting iOS and app preferences since we're on a real device
info: [debug] Starting iOS device log capture via deviceconsole
info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session
info: [debug] Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:1001:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:792:34)
info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: spawn ENOENT)","code":"ENOENT","errno":"ENOENT","syscall":"spawn","origValue":"spawn ENOENT"},"sessionId":null}

error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: spawn ENOENT

info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 1368.579 ms - 197 

info: [debug] Not setting device type since we're connected to a device

info: [debug] Creating iDevice object with udid 0058679bc8d12f8a56243d8de88b0d7e14dc09c0
info: [debug] Couldn't find ideviceinstaller, trying built-in at /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/build/libimobiledevice-macosx/ideviceinstaller
info: [debug] Checking app install status using: /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/build/fruitstrap/fruitstrap isInstalled --id 0058679bc8d12f8a56243d8de88b0d7e14dc09c0 --bundle com.sg.application.TestApp2

info: [debug] App is installed.

info: [debug] fullReset not requested. No need to install.
info: [debug] Starting command proxy.

info: [debug] Instruments socket server started at /tmp/instruments_sock

info: [debug] Starting instruments

info: [debug] Instruments is at: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments

info: Launching instruments

info: [debug] Attempting to run app on real device with UDID 0058679bc8d12f8a56243d8de88b0d7e14dc09c0

info: [debug] Spawning instruments with command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate -D /tmp/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace -w 0058679bc8d12f8a56243d8de88b0d7e14dc09c0 com.sg.application.TestApp2 -e UIASCRIPT /Users/rsangili/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-3fd3829137e4c5d0.js -e UIARESULTSPATH /tmp/appium-instruments
info: [debug] And extra without-delay env: {}

info: [debug] And launch timeouts (in ms): {"global":90000}

info: Instruments is ready to receive commands

info: [debug] Instruments launched. Starting poll loop for new commands.
info: [debug] Setting bootstrap config keys/values
info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: "target = $.target();\nau = $;\n$.isVerbose = true;\nautoAcceptAlerts = false;\n"

info: [debug] Sending command to instruments: target = $.target();
au = $;
$.isVerbose = true;
autoAcceptAlerts = false;

info: [debug] Socket data received (2 bytes)
info: [debug] Socket data being routed.
info: [debug] Sending command to instruments: target = $.target();
au = $;
$.isVerbose = true;
autoAcceptAlerts = false;


info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.108 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: [debug] Socket data received (28 bytes)

info: [debug] Socket data being routed.

info: [debug] Got result from instruments: {"status":0,"value":false}
info: [debug] Setting initial orientation to PORTRAIT
info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: "au.setScreenOrientation('PORTRAIT')"
info: [debug] Sending command to instruments: au.setScreenOrientation('PORTRAIT')
info: [debug] Sending command to instruments: au.setScreenOrientation('PORTRAIT')

info: [debug] [INST] 2014-09-23 19:45:56 +0000 Debug: evaluation finished


info: [debug] [INST] 2014-09-23 19:45:56 +0000 Debug: responding with:


info: [debug] [INST] 2014-09-23 19:45:56 +0000 Debug: Running system command #1: /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js /tmp/instruments_sock 2,{"status":0,"value":false}...


info: [debug] [INST] 2014-09-23 19:45:57 +0000 Debug: Got new command 1 from instruments: au.setScreenOrientation('PORTRAIT')


info: [debug] [INST] 2014-09-23 19:45:57 +0000 Debug: evaluating au.setScreenOrientation('PORTRAIT')


info: [debug] [INST] 2014-09-23 19:45:57 +0000 Debug: target.setDeviceOrientation("1")


info: [debug] [INST] 2014-09-23 19:45:59 +0000 Debug: evaluation finished


info: [debug] [INST] 2014-09-23 19:45:59 +0000 Debug: responding with:


info: [debug] [INST] 2014-09-23 19:45:59 +0000 Debug: Running system command #2: /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js /tmp/instruments_sock 2,{"status":0,"value":"PORTRAIT"}...


info: [debug] Socket data received (33 bytes)

info: [debug] Socket data being routed.
info: [debug] Got result from instruments: {"status":0,"value":"PORTRAIT"}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.142 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.144 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.349 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.129 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
```

iOS Simulator:

[image]

IOS REAL DEVICE:

[image][image]

Comment: you're doing better than me. I haven't found a good page to walk me through step 1 of launching the Appium Inspector while using iOS Simulator. Where are you finding these iOS Settings widgets? I don't see them in the Appium app or the iOS Simulator. I am miss something super basic. Thanks!

Comment: ^^ I figured this out. I was being foiled by it being "too easy".  For iOS Settings, if anyone else is wondering, just click the Apple icon on that top of the GUI.

Answer (score 12):

Why are you trying to run iOS automation on a real device?
**That's a bad idea.**

iOS Automation on a real device is notoriously slow and problematic.

For automation, you want solid and reliable. **Use the iPhone Simulator.**

#### Steps to using iPhone Simulator:

1. Uncheck UDID
2. Uncheck BundleId
3. Check Force Device
4. Set Force Device to "iPhone Simulator"
5. Launch Appium Server
6. Launch Appium Inspector

#### Steps to using a real device:

1. Uncheck the App Path capability
2. Check Force Device
3. Set Force Device to "iPhone 5", "iPhone 5S", "iPhone 4", etc etc. (whatever device you're trying to automate on)
4. Launch Appium Server
5. Launch Appium Inspector

Comment: Ok, Thank you.  I tried with Simulator, but I am getting the below errorinfo: [debug] [INST STDERR] posix spawn failure; aborting launch (binary == /Users/rsangili/Desktop/temp/Payload/TestApp2.app/TestApp2).


info: [debug] [INST STDERR] Instruments Trace Error : Error Starting Recording

Comment: Appium.app sometimes has a bug where it will try and unpack the `.app` file which is what you're seeing here. It's actually pointing to `/Users/rsangili/Desktop/temp/Payload/TestApp2.app/TestApp2` when it should be pointing to `TestApp2.app`. I'm afraid you'll need to use the command line to run Appium.

Comment: Ask another Stack Overflow question for how to install Appium via command line

Comment: @sheeptest I'm trying to create sample ipa file to test on real device , I couldn't find instructions how to do , can you please clarify ? I could find instructions for simulators here https://aaronpresley.com/building-ios-app-use-appium-gui/

Comment: Why are you doing it on a real device? I suggest against it.

Comment: @sheeptest, would you be kind enough to help me understand to get to a solution for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39484982/access-toggle-button-in-android-settings-using-appium-whlie-client-is-written-in