# Appium - Command line

Tags: ios7.1, appium

Team,

Can you please guide me or point me some tutorials to run Appium through command line? I see lot of issues with Appium.app on MAC. It would be great, if you can share your knowledge or materials for me to move forward to run a sample application with appium through command line. Please refer my settings in appium.app for your reference.

[Appium - Not able to launch the inspector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003675/appium-not-able-to-launch-the-inspector)

Logs:

```
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.335 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: --> GET /wd/hub/sessions {}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":[]}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/sessions 200 2.145 ms - 23 {"status":0,"value":[]}
info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"platformName":"iOS","platformVersion":"7.1","newCommandTimeout":"999999","automationName":"Appium","deviceName":"iPhone Simulator"}}
info: [debug] Using local app from command line: /Users/rsangili/Desktop/temp/Payload/TestApp2.app
info: [debug] Creating new appium session dd2c8121-6a13-48be-8a0b-9fc6233437a5
info: [debug] Removing any remaining instruments sockets
info: [debug] Cleaned up instruments socket /tmp/instruments_sock
info: [debug] Setting Xcode folder
info: [debug] Setting Xcode version
info: [debug] Setting iOS SDK Version
info: [debug] iOS SDK Version set to 7.1
info: [debug] Detecting automation tracetemplate
info: [debug] Not auto-detecting udid, running on sim
error: Could not parse plist file (as binary) at /Users/rsangili/Desktop/temp/Payload/TestApp2.app/en.lproj/Localizable.strings
info: Will try to parse the plist file as XML
error: Could not parse plist file (as XML) at /Users/rsangili/Desktop/temp/Payload/TestApp2.app/en.lproj/Localizable.strings
warn: Could not parse app Localizable.strings
info: [debug] Not setting locale
info: [debug] Creating instruments
info: [debug] Preparing uiauto bootstrap
info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap dir:
info: [debug] Dynamic env:
info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap code:
info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap path:
info: [debug] Reusing dynamic bootstrap:
info: [debug] Fixing device was changed from:"
info: [debug] No iOS / app preferences to set
info: [debug] Starting iOS 7.* simulator log capture
info: [debug] Killing the simulator process
info: [debug] Killing any other simulator daemons
info: [debug] Checking whether instruments supports our device string
info: [debug] Getting list of devices instruments supports
info: [debug] Instruments is at: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments
info: [debug] Fixing device was changed from:"
info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session
error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Command failed: 
info: [debug] Error: Command failed: 
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:648:15)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Command failed: )","killed":true,"code":null,"signal":"SIGTERM","origValue":"Command failed: "},"sessionId":null}
info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 6381.780 ms - 199
```

Thanks,
Ramesh

Answer (score 9):

## Using Appium from Command Line

#### Installation

1. Open a terminal session
2. Install homebrew ([instructions](http://brew.sh/))
3. Run the below commands

---

```
 $ brew install node # install node and npm
 $ npm install -g appium # globally install appium
 $ npm install wd
 $ appium # Launch your appium server!
```

#### Usage

Whenever you want to begin an appium server session, type `appium` to run the server.

Arguments can be added to that command.

`appium --app path/to/app --device-name "iPhone Simulator"`

## Using Appium.app inspector with server

In my development env setup, I don't use the Appium.app server, but I **DO** use the inspector.

1. Start your Appium server with the `--app` and `--device-name` arguments
2. Click on the Appium.app inspector icon
3. The iPhone Simulator will launch, and **may** give you an authorization prompt for Instruments to control it

Comment: Thanks for you response. I am facing the below issueusdal1lt00097:deviceconsole rsangili$ sudo grunt authorize-ios
>> Local Npm module "grunt-newer" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-mocha-test" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-jshint" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-jscs-checker" not found. Is it installed?
Warning: Task "authorize-ios" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

Comment: I tried the below command usdal1lt00097:deviceconsole rsangili$ appium --app /Users/rsangili/Desktop/temp/Payload/TestApp2.app --device-name "iPhone Simulator"
info: Welcome to Appium v1.2.2 (REV cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4)
info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
info: [debug] Non-default server args: {"app":"/Users/rsangili/Desktop/temp/Payload/TestApp2.app","deviceName":"iPhone Simulator"}
info: LogLevel: debug

Comment: My simulator is not not getting launched and there is no indication in the logs

Comment: Your simulator will only be launched when you start the inspector or when your test starts the webdriver

Comment: `sudo grunt authorize-ios` isn't needed as long as you accept the manual prompt to give Instruments access to your simulator when it launches

Comment: my simulator is getting closed as soon as I clicked on the inspector. Attached latest logs to the ticket.

Comment: 1. Quit the simulator before launch, 2. Remove these desired_capabilities: "newCommandTimeout":"999999","automationName":"Appium"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61857/discussion-between-ramesh-sangili-and-sheeptest).

Comment: @sheeptest.  When you set capabilities like '--device-name' in the terminal, how do you then create an instance of the driver in your code?  Do you still create DesiredCapabilities in the code but with device name excluded?

Comment: It depends on what i'm trying to do! I've done it both ways and neither is right/wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Setting up Appium

```
Mac:
```

Download and install Latest Java from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
Download and install latest Android SDK from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
Configure path to ANDROID_HOME and JAVA_HOME in .bash profile
Configure path to Platform-tools and tools folder in .bash profile
Install ruby

Install brew

```
    ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew/go/install)"
```

Set path for brew from .bash profile

```
  export PATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH"
  export MANPATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/share/man:$MANPATH"
  export INFOPATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/share/info:$INFOPATH"
```

Install node:Paste the below commands one by one  at terminal and hit enter

```
  brew update
  brew install node
  brew link node
```

Install appium

```
  npm install -g appium


  npm install wd
```

To start appium: Paste the below command at terminal and hit enter

```
  appium
```

Install Appium python client:
Download source from
https://github.com/appium/python-client
Extract it, Navigate to the folder containing the Python client from terminal and install by:
cd python-client

```
python setup.py install
```

IDE used: Pycharm

```
Linux:
```

Download and install Latest Java from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
Download and install latest Android SDK from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
    Configure path to ANDROID_HOME and JAVA_HOME in .bashrc profile
Configure path to Platform-tools and tools folder in .bashrc profile
command gedit.bashrc to open bash profile and specify path
Install ruby
Install linux brew 
      ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew/go/install)"

Steps to get appium working on ubuntu pc :

Install ruby: Paste the below command at terminal and hit enter

```
  sudo apt-get install build-essential curl git m4 ruby texinfo libbz2-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libexpat-dev libncurses-dev zlib1g-dev
```

Install linux brew:Paste the below command at terminal and hit enter 
      ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew/go/install)"

set path for brew

Type: gedit.bashrc at terminal and copy paste following into the .bashrc file

```
  export PATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH"
  export MANPATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/share/man:$MANPATH"
  export INFOPATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/share/info:$INFOPATH"
```

Install node:Paste the below commands one by one  at terminal and hit enter

```
  brew update
  brew install node
  brew link node
```

Install appium

```
  npm install -g appium


  npm install wd
```

To start appium: Paste the below command at terminal and hit enter

```
  appium
```

Install Appium python client:
Download source from
https://github.com/appium/python-client
Extract it, Navigate to the folder containing the Python client from terminal and install by:
      cd python-client

```
 python setup.py install
```

IDE used: Spyder/Pycharm
You can get spyder by running command
        Sudo apt-get install Spyder
    Windows:

Download and install python 2.7.9 from https://www.python.org/downloads/
Download and install Latest Java from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
Download Android SDK from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
Set Environment variables to JAVA_HOME for Java , Python.exe  for python and ANDROID_HOME to Android sdk, and Android Tools and platform tools.

IDE used: Pycharm

Download and install pycharm IDE from https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/
Install Appium python client:
Download source from
https://github.com/appium/python-client
Extract it, Navigate to the folder containing the Python client from terminal and install by:
cd python-client

python setup.py install
Start node server by using Appium gui from windows PC